# How to include rows of data in a single django model entry?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on multiple django sites and have been limited in making my project look nice for clients.

For example in the same app I have two models images and image galleries. It would be so much nicer to just have an admin entry for galleries and in that a table of images.

Comment: Do you like your galleries have inline table with images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) is for. Taken a models.py like this:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Image(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField()
   gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
```

You create an admin.py like this and only register an admin class for the Gallery:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Image

class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageInline]

admin.site.register(Gallery, GalleryAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks Eschler, this is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution thanks to Dirk's help.

```
from django.db import models

PHOTO_PATH = 'media_gallery'

class Gallerys(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Title of the image maximum 30 characters.')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='date', help_text='This is automatic, used in the URL.')
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Image Galleries"
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Images(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Title of the image maximum 30 characters.')
    content = models.FileField(upload_to=PHOTO_PATH,blank=False, help_text='Ensure the image size is small and it\'s aspect ratio is 16:9.')
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallerys)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Images"
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

import models
from django.contrib import admin

class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Images

class GallerysAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date', 'slug')
    inlines = [ImageInline]

admin.site.register(models.Gallerys,GallerysAdmin)
```